# Uh, what's going on with the captcha?

Tags: support, bug, captcha

Yes, I am a human being, but I don't see a captcha nor a field to enter whatever is expected here...

[image]

Comment: Browser? Version? OS?

Comment: Mac OS X, Firefox 13 - though this doesn't seem like a browser compatibility problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Did you blow away cache/cookies? Captcha is working okay for me in Chrome and Firefox 12... (Also that standard disable adblock)

Comment: Not sure, have never had to blow away cookies on any SE site. I wasn't able to post an answer to [a question that was migrated from SO](http://serverfault.com/questions/392369/do-i-really-need-a-128gb-pagefile/) but then tried the same in Safari just now, no problem. So not sure if it was a transient issue but now it seems to be working ok. Am I the first/only person to ever see this?

Comment: Is it still happening? http://meta.serverfault.com/captcha

Comment: @Ben yes, different image now (all humans are dead). I see the same image in a different browser, but the actual captcha is there. I also see the captcha correctly in FireFox 13 on my other computer, same OS, same build.

Comment: Oh, technically you were on http://serverfault.com/captcha

Comment: Yep, still broken there. I can add answers unlike before, but I assume that's because I'm no longer going through the verification.

Comment: Do you use HTTPS Everywhere?

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff no, I don't...

Comment: Oh. ):  It sounded like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89494/captcha-failed-to-display) possibly.  Anything else doing https stuff?

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff No, this is pretty standard stuff... clicked on a migrated link from SO for a question that was migrated here, entered an answer, and was prompted with the above page - which looks just like the normal captcha page, but no captcha. I see the same on the link Ben provided as well, which is not https:// ... do you see the captcha there?

Comment: Disable any and all plugins and extensions you've got.  Sure sounds like something's blocking it from getting pulled in...

Comment: The only add-in I have is Google Redesigned. Disabling it and restarting Firefox yields the same thing. And I'm using the same add-on on my other computer, which is the same OS, same build of Firefox etc., and the captcha works fine there. I am seeing the same thing at http://stackoverflow.com/captcha

Comment: proxy?  what else do you have that would interfere?

Comment: Nothing... as I've stated it works in Safari, another browser on this machine, so I don't think a proxy (which I don't even use) could be blamed. I am connected directly to my router with a dedicated 35/35 connection.

Comment: More than willing to allow someone to use LogMeIn or some similar technology to sniff around at my settings, if it will help the site or other users who come across this issue in the future.

Comment: In case there's any question that my Internet speed is somehow preventing the captcha widget from loading: http://www.speedtest.net/result/1970168410.png

Comment: Did this ever get reproduced/resolved ?

Comment: @Iain no, still happening for me on this machine in Firefox 13.